# Previously working adapter methods crashing app

Tags: c#, android, ios, bluetooth, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app. I uses the [`Monkey.Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Getting%20Started/Mobile_Stack) plugin. I have based my app on [this](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/BluetoothHeartRateMonitor) sample. It has been previously working. However, having moved the code in full into another project, the last two methods (triggered by the adapter), are causing the app the crash. Only when both are commented out, does the app run. I don't see why this would be, as they are unchanged from the sample where they worked?

```
namespace Gas_Sense
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        IAdapter adapter;
        ObservableCollection<IDevice> devices;

        public HomePage(IAdapter adapter)
        {   
            InitializeComponent();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();

            NewDeviceButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {

                adapter.StartScanningForDevices (0x180D.UuidFromPartial ()); 

                await Task.Delay (5000); // wait 5 seconds for the scan to complete
                adapter.StopScanningForDevices();

                //user selects the device which goes into var strip as IDevice
                    adapter.ConnectToDevice (strip); 
                }
            };

            adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender, DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e) => {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    devices.Add (e.Device);
                });
            };

            adapter.ScanTimeoutElapsed += (sender, e) => {
                adapter.StopScanningForDevices(); // not sure why it doesn't stop already, if the timeout elapses... or is this a fake timeout we made?
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
                    IsBusy = false;
                    DisplayAlert("Timeout", "Bluetooth scan timeout elapsed, no Devices were found", "OK");
                });
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Any ideas would be very welcome, as this one has me quite stumped... I haven't added the packages references, but there are a few other nuget packages referenced. however, not sure that they would have this effect?

UPDATE:

So when I comment out those two lines and press a button to trigger another function which calls an adapter method to start scanning for BLE devices, the app crashes too. So it seems to be an issue with the plugin / nuget set up. Or adapter set up?

Comment: Not sure if the references or other files are relevant, but it is definitely the adapter methods making the app crash...